# Best way to require all files from a directory in ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, directory, require

What's the best way to require all files from a directory in ruby ?

Answer (score 503, accepted):

How about:

```
Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

Comment: You'll need to drop the .rb before requiring.  Good other than that

Comment: According to the Pickaxe, the .rb extension is optional.  Technically it changes the meaning: "require 'foo.rb'" requires foo.rb, whereas "require 'foo'" might require foo.rb, foo.so or foo.dll.

Comment: @Pete, is this still true? See [Rene's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby#comment9237243_2231511) below.

Comment: This might be obvious, but its worth noting that dropping the .rb will also require any non-.rb files in the dir, which might not be desired.

Comment: @louism I think the discussion is actually about dropping the `.rb` from the `require` portion: `Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file[0..-4] }`

Comment: @PeteHodgson's suggestion is inaccurate. Ruby's `require` is not confused by the presence or absence of the `.rb` extension. Tested on MRI 1.8.7-p374, 2.1.5 and 2.2.0 tested. This urban legend comes from Rails, where "clever" autoloading exhibited the behaviour he describes in older versions (and may still exhibit it).

Comment: make sure to sort files first, for not introducing randomness caused by OS and keep require order deterministic:

`Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].sort.each {|file| require file }`

Comment: even more concise would be: 

        `Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each(&method(:require))`

Answer (score 365):

If it's a directory relative to the file that does the requiring (e.g. you want to load all files in the lib directory):

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }
```

**Edit:** Based on comments below, an updated version:

```
Dir[File.join(__dir__, 'lib', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
```

Comment: You can also add all child directories like this `Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/support/**/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }`

Comment: It's probably safer to use File.join rather than making assumptions about forward/backward slashes: `Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib', '*.rb')].each {|file| require file }`

Comment: @ChristopherPatuzzo you are a live saver. I couldn't figure out why the files were never loaded. "\current\file\path/lib/*.rb"

Comment: There is also require_relative

Comment: If you're using >= ruby 2.0, you can use `__dir__` instead of `File.dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: @maasha How do you use `require_relative` to require all files in a directory?

Answer (score 108):

Try the require_all gem:

1. http://github.com/jarmo/require_all
2. https://rubygems.org/gems/require_all

It lets you simply:

```
require_all 'path/to/directory'
```

Comment: I needed to include all of my ActiveRecord models, the require_all gem figured out all of the dependencies and required them perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @panupan Just be aware that `require_all`'s cyclic dependency resolution works around a problem in your source code: you have Ruby source files that do not require their dependencies. This shuts the door on scalpel loading, committing you to all-or-nothing loading. That's not a problem in small libraries, but it's a decision you should be making consciously.

Comment: It doesn't have sense to bloat your app with gems that you can simply replace with a line of code. This increases the load time of your app and induces more bugs at long term.

Answer (score 53):

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib/*.rb'].each do |file| 
  require File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
end
```

If you don't strip the extension then you may end up requiring the same file twice (ruby won't realize that "foo" and "foo.rb" are the same file). Requiring the same file twice can lead to spurious warnings (e.g. "warning: already initialized constant").

Comment: Is this really the case? Documentation says: A feature will not be loaded if its name already appears in $". The file name is converted to an absolute path, so "require 'a'; require './a'" will not load a.rb twice. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001418

Comment: My testing shows the same that Derek said: `require "foo.rb"; require "foo";` will load `foo.rb` just once.

Comment: @PeteHodgson- Can you back this up?

Comment: No. Ruby's `require` is not confused by the presence or absence of the `.rb` extension. Tested on MRI 1.8.7-p374, 2.1.5 and 2.2.0. This urban legend comes from Rails, where "clever" autoloading exhibited the behaviour described in older versions (and may still exhibit it).

Answer (score 49):

```
Dir.glob(File.join('path', '**', '*.rb'), &method(:require))
```

or alternatively, if you want to scope the files to load to specific folders:

```
Dir.glob(File.join('path', '{folder1,folder2}', '**', '*.rb'), &method(:require))
```

**explanation:**

[Dir.glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) takes a block as argument.

method(:require) [will return the require method.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-method)

&method(:require) will convert the method to a bloc.

Comment: This is some beautiful code. I love how there are no visible blocks.

Comment: `Dir.glob( File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), '{lib,addons}', 'subfolder', '**', '*.rb' ), &method(:require) )` eliminates dependence on platform (such as '/' or '\'). Works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

The best way is to add the directory to the load path and then `require` the basename of each file.  This is because you want to avoid accidentally requiring the same file twice -- often  not the intended behavior.  Whether a file will be loaded or not is dependent on whether `require` has seen the path passed to it before.  For example, this simple irb session shows that you can mistakenly require and load the same file twice.

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'test'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require './test'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> require './test.rb'
=> false
irb(main):004:0> require 'test'
=> false
```

Note that the first two lines return `true` meaning the same file was loaded both times.  When paths are used, even if the paths point to the same location, `require` doesn't know that the file was already required.

Here instead, we add a directory to the load path and then require the basename of each *.rb file within.

```
dir = "/path/to/directory"
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(dir)
Dir[File.join(dir, "*.rb")].each {|file| require File.basename(file) }
```

If you don't care about the file being required more than once, or your intention is just to load the contents of the file, perhaps `load` should be used instead of `require`.  Use load in this case, because it better expresses what you're trying to accomplish.  For example:

```
Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| load file }
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution to require all files while avoiding any accidental double requiring of files - and should be marked as the accepted answer ...

Comment: I feel like something has changed since 2009. `require` now needs `./` and `require_relative` realises those are paths to the same file.

Answer (score 17):

```
Dir[File.join(__dir__, "/app/**/*.rb")].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

This will work recursively on your local machine and a remote (Like Heroku) which does not use relative paths.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of concatenating paths like in some answers, I use `File.expand_path`:

```
Dir[File.expand_path('importers/*.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__))].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

**Update:**

Instead of using `File.dirname` you could do the following:

```
Dir[File.expand_path('../importers/*.rb', __FILE__)].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

Where `..` strips the filename of `__FILE__`.

Comment: this seems definitely the way to go, and most up to date answer, after trying all the rest, +1 for `File.expand_path`

Comment: I definitely prefer this answer to the accepted one.  Various `Rails.root.join` answers also work if you're in rails.

Answer (score 8):

In Rails, you can do:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'ext', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }
```

Update: Corrected with suggestion of @Jiggneshh Gohel to remove slashes.

Comment: Since `Rails.root` is a [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) instance, you can do this in any Ruby environment, not just Rails (N.B. `Rails.root.join('lib/ext/*.rb')` reads a little nicer)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation; I edited to include your comment.

Comment: Using a forward slash (/) for sub-directories under Rails.root, for e.g. `Rails.root.join('/lib')` doesn't generate correct path. I found this one to work correctly: `Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'ext', '*.rb')].each { |file| require file }`

Comment: @Jiggneshh Gohel I removed slashes as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a few years late to the party, but I kind of like this one-line solution I used to get rails to include everything in app/workers/concerns:

`Dir[ Rails.root.join *%w(app workers concerns *) ].each{ |f| require f }`

Answer (score 1):

For Ruby older than 3.0, [Rubocop warns](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Lint/NonDeterministicRequireOrder) against the accepted answer because load order is not deterministic for all OSes. Linux sorts upper and lower case differently than Mac or Windows. The following does what the OP requested for all versions of Ruby:

```rb
Dir['/path/to/directory/*.rb'].sort.each { |file| require file }
```

The following recurses through all subdirectories for all versions of Ruby:

```rb
Dir['/path/to/directory/**/*.rb'].sort.each { |file| require file }
```

Ruby 3.0 and later sort files consistently, so the following is all that is needed if you know that older Ruby versions will never be used:

```rb
Dir['/path/to/directory/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

The following recurses through all subdirectories for Ruby 3.0 and later:

```rb
Dir['/path/to/directory/**/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are great. To add, if you want to do this automagically, you can use [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk), which is what Rails uses to load files.

```
require 'zeitwerk'
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
loader.push_dir('main/src/dir')
loader.setup
```

Then everything has access to everything

Answer (score -2):

And what about: `require_relative *Dir['relative path']`?

Comment: Require relative doesn't take multiple files:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative

Comment: OK, but in my example it isn't. The '*' changes arity to 1. It works as multiple call to require_relative.

Comment: _The '*' changes arity to 1_ - What do you mean with it? `require_relative *Dir['*.rb']` work, if there is only one ruby-script. But if multiple ruby scripts are found, you get `require_relative': wrong number of arguments (4 for 1) (ArgumentError)`