# Cleanest/One-liner way to require all files in directory in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, require

When creating gems, I often have a directory structure like this:

```
|--lib
    |-- helpers.rb
    `-- helpers
        |-- helper_a.rb
        `-- helper_b.rb
```

Inside the `helpers.rb`, I'm just `require`-ing the files in the `helpers` directory.  But I have to do things like this:

```
$:.push(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/helpers')
require 'helper_a'
require 'helper_b'
```

Is there a way to make that one line so I never have to add to it?  I just came up with this real quick:

```
dir = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "helpers")
Dir.entries(dir)[2..-1].each { |file| require "#{dir}/#{file[0..-4]}" }
```

But it's two lines and ugly.  What slick tricks have you done to make this a one liner?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby - use `Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }`

Comment: Even nicer, use the require_all gem mentioned in that question.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
project_root = File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))
Dir.glob(project_root + '/helpers/*') {|file| require file}
```

Or to golf it a bit more:

```
Dir.glob(project_root + '/helpers/*', &method(:require))
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought about method#to_proc, nice!

Comment: I would've require to understand wildcards... but +1 and thanks for the time you've save me... :D

Comment: @Yasky It didn't, but now it does (had to stick a call to `absolute_path` in there)

Answer (score 3):

I like require_relative:

```
Dir.glob('lib/**/*.rb') { |f| require_relative f }
```

The `&method(:require_relative) trick won't work with require_relative.  I get:

```
`require_relative': cannot infer basepath (LoadError)
```

But it does save the hassle of computing `project_root`

I'm using `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
# helpers.rb
Dir[__dir__ + '/helpers/*'].each &method(:require)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the cleanest way I have discovered is to use Dir.glob with wild cards.

Put the following in your rakefile:

```
gem.files = Dir.glob('lib/**/ *.rb')
```

It should work a treat.

Comment: This did not answer the question about using require.