# Ruby plugin architecture

Tags: ruby, plugins

I have to develop a plugin based software in ruby. What's the best architeture tu use?

I am thinking about plugin like this, each in a separate .rb file:

```
class MyPlugin < Plugin

def info
 infos
end

def run
 # run
end
end
```

How i can write a plugin manager to call these plugins?

Comment: You might also consider using `Module` s with `include` or `extend`.

Comment: most ruby plugins come in the form of gems, check this tutorial out as a resource http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/, which also covers a conventional architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to clearly define what "calling the plugins" exactly mean.

For start, you can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby) how to `require` all the files from a directory, put your plugins into a single directory and require them all.

Then you need to somehow pick which one to use, whether it be:

- passing its classname as a string through a command line argument or a config file parameter, and looking for a class by that name using [`const_get`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_get), or
- presenting a user a list of all plugins (all descendants of your `Plugin` class) - check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393697/look-up-all-descendants-of-a-class-in-ruby) how to do it

Finally, you instantiate your plugin and do whatever you need to do with it.