# How to execute some procedure in all ruby files in current directory?

Tags: ruby, file

I'm new to Ruby - I'm having troubles on every step...

Imagine a Ruby script **main.rb** and a lot of unknown script files **script1.rb** ... **scriptN.rb**.
Each **scriptX.rb** contains unique module with one procedure needs to be executed:

```
Module X  
  def some_procedure(i)  
    puts "{#i} Module X procedure executed successfully!"  
  end  
end
```

All I need is to:

1. iterate over all files in current directory
2. if current file has name like `/^script.*?\.rb$/`
3. then load it and execute some_procedure

How can I do it in **main.rb** ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Choose from these great answers in SO on loading the files: [Best way to require all files from a directory in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby)

Then in your files, just have them execute on load, rather than on a method call.

Comment: Thank You, but it is not what is required.
Now I want to execute **some_procedure()** - so I have to put it to each module to execute on load.
What if later I will need to execute **another_procedure()** ?
Do I have to rewrite all these modules?!

Comment: Personally, I think when you have too many assumptions on the naming of each module. Instead, I would a) follow my guidelines able b) have each module insert the names of the methods to be executes into a global hash. Then c) execute all methods in the hash. Yours feels very un-ruby (to me. but obviously if it works, that's all that REALLY matters).

Comment: I think, You are right. Thanks for advice of using global hash. I will post news solution below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that, when a file is required, it doesn't return the list of modules (or, in general, constants) which it defines. So, unless you don't know which module a script has defined, you will not know where to pass your `some_procedure` message.

As a workaround, you may try [getting the list](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/constants/class) of defined constants before and after the script was required, find a [difference](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/-), i.e. list of constants during `require`, and [iterate](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/each) through all of them, checking [which one implements](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%3F) the method you need.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I've encountered.
I've almost broke my brains, but think I've found solution!
Look my solution below...

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to put some restriction:

- Every file **script_my1.rb** will have the module named **Script_my1**. I.e. first letter capitalized, all other letters - lowercase.

Create two files **script_my1.rb** and **script_my2.rb** as follows:

---**script_my1.rb**:

```
module Script_my1  
  @value = 0  

  def self.some_procedure(i)  
    puts "#{i} my1 executed!"  
    @value = i  
  end  

  def self.another_procedure()  
    return @value  
  end  
end
```

---**script_my2.rb**:

```
module Script_my2  
  @value = 0

  def self.some_procedure(i)  
    puts "#{i} my2 executed!"  
    @value = i  
  end  

  def self.another_procedure()  
    return @value  
  end  
end
```

Now the main script, that loads and executes **some_procedure()** in each module, and then **another_procedure()**.

Please notice, that each module can have separated variables with the same name **@value**.

Moreover, I think every module can be executed in a separate thread and have access to global variables, but I have not tested it yet.

---**main.rb**:

```
# Load all files from the current directory  
# with name like script_xxx.rb  
i = 1  
result = nil  
Dir['./script_*.rb'].each { |f|  
  next if File.directory?(f)  

  require (f)  
  moduleName = f[2,f.length].rpartition('.rb')[0].capitalize  
  eval ( "#{moduleName}.some_procedure(%d)" % i )  
  eval ( "result = #{moduleName}.another_procedure()" )  
  puts result  
  i = i + 1  
}
```

Output of this program is:

```
1 my1 executed!
1
2 my2 executed!
2
```

That is all!

Comment: This assumes that naming of modules follows naming of the ruby files they are contained within, which was not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvement to previous solution can be made. If we want to avoid special naming, we can use global hash to store procedure's names. Each loaded **script_xx.rb** file would register it's own procedures in this global hash.

Please notice, that in this case we make two cycles:

1. first we load all files **script_xx.b**

   every file while loading will register it's procedures in **$global_procs** array.
2. then iterate over all entries in **$global_procs** to execute all registered procedures via **eval()**

Hope, this is a more 'ruby-like' solution!

---***script_my1.rb***

```
module My1  
  @value = 0  

  def self.some_procedure(i)  
    puts "#{i} my1 executed!"  
    @value = i  
  end  

  def self.another_procedure()  
    return @value  
  end  
end 

$global_procs << { 'module' => 'My1',
  'some_procedure' => 'My1.some_procedure',
  'another_procedure' => 'My1.another_procedure' }
```

---***script_my2.rb***

```
module MMM2  
  @value = 0

  def self.some_procedure(i)  
    puts "#{i} MMM2 executed!"  
    @value = i  
  end  

  def self.another_procedure()  
    return @value  
  end  
end  

$global_procs << { 'module' => 'MMM2',
  'some_procedure' => 'MMM2.some_procedure',
  'another_procedure' => 'MMM2.another_procedure' }
```

---**main.rb**

```
# Create global array for holding module's info
$global_procs = []

Dir['./script_*.rb'].each { |f|  
  next if File.directory?(f)  
  require (f)  
}

i = 1  
result = nil  

$global_procs.each { |p|
  puts "Module name: " + p['module']
  eval(p['some_procedure']+'(i)')
  result = eval(p['another_procedure']+'()')
  puts result  
  i = i + 1  
}
```