# Require all files in sub-directory

Tags: ruby, filesystems, require

I have the following directory tree.

```
- app.rb
- folder/
  - one/
    - one.rb
  - two/
    - two.rb
```

I want to be able to load Ruby files in the folder/ directory, even the ones in the sub-directories. How would I do so?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby . Use the *require_all* gem and do `require 'require_all'; require_rel 'one'` in `one.rb`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Jekyll](http://www.jekyllrb.com/) does something similar with its plugins. Something like this should do the trick:

```
    Dir[File.join(".", "**/*.rb")].each do |f|
      require f
    end
```

Comment: In case you have inheritance, you'll want to sort the files that are required so that the top level classes are required first. Dir[File.join("#{Rails.root}/app/classes", "**/*.rb")].sort_by {|path| path.split("/").length }.each do |f|
  require f
end

Answer (score 18):

With less code, but still working on Linux, OS X and Windows:

```
Dir['./**/*.rb'].each{ |f| require f }
```

The `'.'` is needed for Ruby 1.9.2 where the current directory is no longer part of the path.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(".", "**", "*.rb")).each do |file|
   require file
end
```

Comment: This will break on Ruby 1.9.2+, since '.' is no longer part of the search path for requires. An explicit leading '.' or `require_relative` is required.

Answer (score 2):

In my project this evaluates to `["./fixset.rb", "./spec/fixset_spec.rb", "./spec/spec_helper.rb"]` which causes my specs to run twice.  Therefore, here's a tweaked version:

```
Dir[File.join(".", "**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f unless f[/^\.\/spec\//]}
```

This'll safely ignore all *.rb files in `./spec/`