# Rspec testing models from a custom directory

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I have some classes in app/custom

In `/custom` I have a bunch of other folders with classes. From the app I only use `app/custom/*rb` but for testing purposes I would want to directly access all subfolders and their classes. 
Is this possible? I realise Rspec likes to look in the typical directories for its testing, but I need this directory to be loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you just require all the needed files in your `spec_helper.rb`? Something like this might work:

```
Dir[File.join('custom', '**', '*.rb')].each {|f| require_relative f}
```

or

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('custom', '**', '*.rb')].each {|f| require f}
```

Ideas for that code found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby).