# How to 'require' all files from a directory and its sub-directories (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to `require` all the projects from the `projects` and `sub_projects` folders.

Dir Structure:

```
|-- project_manager
    -- run_farm.rb
    -- projects
       -- build_coop.rb
       -- sub_projects
          -- count_apples.rb
          -- count_chickens.rb
```

I found this answer but was unable to get it to work: [Best way to require all files from a directory in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735073/best-way-to-require-all-files-from-a-directory-in-ruby)

Original syntax from the link: `Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }`

So, in run_farm.rb, I tried this:

```
path_to_directory = File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))
Dir[path_to_directory + '/projects/**/*'].each { |file| require file }
```

Also tried:

```
path_to_directory = File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))
Dir[path_to_directory + '/projects/**/*'].each { |file| require "#{file}" }
```

When I run `run_farm.rb`, I get this error: `.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'`

I was able to run this, so I know something works:

```
path_to_directory = File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__))
Dir[path_to_directory + '/projects/**/*'].each { |file| puts "#{file}" }
```

Found this but it didn't help me: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1158

I hope I provided enough info. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me when I change `'/projects/**/*'` to `'/projects/**/*.rb'`.  I put the line `puts "in file blah"` in each of the required files, substituting the actual file name for "blah" to confirm that they were all being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To require all the files, there is a special gem which does an amazing job. It's `require_all` but don't install the lastest one.

Install

```
gem install require_all -v 1.5.0
```

It provides two beautiful methods `require_all()` and `require_rel()`! For require_rel, paths are relative to the caller rather than the current working directory

Comment: What's the problem with the latest version?

Comment: @Jim U When you load file in which If an Inherited super is missing, then it will throw the error. But 1.5.0 checks this after loading all the classes.

Comment: This worked. I used the latest version and did not run into any trouble.